# iOS In App Purchase invalid identifier

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, invalidation

I'm trying to implement IAP for my app and I have read all the available solution but I couldn't find my issue. I've done the following steps:
1. create App ID in apple developer profile with com.Company.projectName ID
2. Add my app with same ID in itunes connect
3. Add IAP to my project with com.Company.projectName as it's ID(Which I have problem as I can't see Auto renewable subscription)
4. Get the valid products with the following code:

```
SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"com.Company.projectName"]];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];
```

5. Add a new apple ID as tester.

I still get invalid identifier when I want to do purchase. I have tried to delete the app and connect the device and build. I have logout my itunes account.
Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

When you are create a new products on ITC , it will take some time to get in a valid product list. Products are reviewed by Apple. When they are in reviewing state, you will a list of product in Invalid prodcuts.

Make sure you have to signed a apple's agreement of tax and banking on itunes connect.

Comment: It's been more than a week but I still get invalid ID. my app status is prepare for submission and my IAP is ready to submit. Do I need to submit my app?

Comment: Where can I find the apple's agreement?

Comment: No need to submit the app. Are you checked in app purchase flow using sanbox account ?

Comment: Login on https://itunesconnect.apple.com/
and see the  section Agreement tax & banking

Comment: I have created the sandbox tester but I don't get to login with that account as I get invalid identifier first

Comment: Dear Rishi
Do I need to setup all the contact,bank and tax info?